# Using data from another method with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, rest

So I have a method which will return an array of objects, but I want to call the method inside the query method which will use linq to return the result. I think this is feasible, but not sure if I'm right or not. The solution I could think of is calling the method & instantiating the array again inside the query  method and then use linq as usual.

```
Class A{
  public Items[] GetItems(){
    Items[] item = new Items[4];
    return items;
    }
  }
```

In another class in another file, which will do some routing with rest. that uses the data from method `GetItems` in class A to make query to the server. May be passing an array as an argument to the `ItemsHandler` method perhaps?

```
  Class B{
  [Route("~api/item")]
  private IEnumerable<Items> ItemsHandler(){
     return A.GetItems();
    }
  }
```

Comment: What sort of LINQ query is this - LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, EF?

Comment: Not really, if it's returning array you can just use it like MyMethod().Where()...

Comment: Can you write some pseudo code to show a sample query? Something that demonstrates the ideal usage from what you describe.

Comment: It sounds fine, but I would need to see some sample/pseudo code as well. (You may want to mark it as such to avoid the "That doesn't compile!" comments)

Comment: Do you mean you want to create a method that takes an array as a parameter and uses LINQ to extract something? That's certainly doable.

Comment: @JohnC: Yes something similar to that

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming I'm reading the question correctly, I think this is at least a start.  We can worry over the specifics if I'm not on a completely wrong track:

```
private string[] Filter(string[] names, string like) {
    return names.Where(n => n.Contains(like)).ToArray();
}
```

`IEnumerable` also has a `.ToList()` method, which is usually more convenient, but you mentioned arrays.  Likewise, if the data elements aren't strings, the condition can be more complex.

You can then call it relatively naturally:

```
string[] names = MethodThatReturnsAnArrayOfNames();
string[] filtered_names = Filter (names, "ar");
```

`Filter()`, of course, can also be public, where that's of use.